# Need to do activity before loading first page of Spring 3 app

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've inherited an existing Spring 3 app and have to make an update to it. The update is a routine that checks a database for a certain condition and, depending on what that condition is, sending the user to one of two landing pages.

Right now, the app goes immediately to the index.htm page when loaded. I need to change the app to first go to a class I'm calling PathFinder. PathFinder is responsible for checking a database for a value. If the value is set, I want the user to be sent to the index.htm page. If it isn't set, I want to send them to itemValuation.htm.

I'm not sure how to accomplish this in the Spring world. Would this be a use-case for an interceptor?

Comment: What handles the request to `index.htm`? Do you know what a `@Controller` is? Do you know what a redirect is? What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, I know what a controller and a redirect is. index.jsp is backed by IndexController. I create a new page called pathfinder.jsp back by PathFinderController. The web.xml welcome-file points to redirect.jsp, which itself redirects to the index page. I changed the jsp to point to the new pathfinder.jsp page. PathFinderController checks the db and returns a ModelAndVIew(RedirectView()) specific to the result of the query. This works, but it doesn't seem that it would be the "correct" way to do it. Creating a blank page with a controller seems complicated for what I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to initialize condition based on database records, you can do in on [`WebApplicationInitializer`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html)

Comment: Thanks Prakash, I'll look at that.